# TypeScript: type for returning an async function call inside a setTimeout()?

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, node-fetch

I have a function for fetching credentials for an external API (oversimplified):

```
const fetchCredentials= async () => {
  return await fetch(/* url and params */);      
};
```

And another one which calls the above and keeps retrying to call if it the response is not ok.

```
const retryFetchCredentials = (initialDelay = 250): Promise<Credentials | void> => {
    
    return fetchCredentials().then(async res => {    
      if (res.ok) {
        const parsedResponse = await res.json() as Credentials ;
        return parsedResponse;
      }
      else {

        // The issue is with this timeout/return:
        setTimeout(() => { 
          return retryFetchCredentials (initialDelay * 2);
        }, initialDelay);

      }        
    });
};
```

My problem is that I don't know how to strongly type the return inside the setTimeOut function, I keep getting a `Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected.` error. I have tried several return types for the function`retryFetchCredentials` to no avail.

Any clues about how to solve this?

Comment: Returning from `setTimeout`'s callback is **not** the same thing as returning from the `.then` callback. You'll likely need to wrap the timeout in a `new Promise` so you can `resolve` the value.

Comment: Ok, this, alongside Lars' answer below, did the trick, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing the `return` from the the function inside `setTimeout` should make the error go away without affecting the behavior of the rest of the code.

As a side note, you shouldn't mix `async`/`await` with `.then` for consistency. And if you use `async`/`await` whenever possible, your code is going to increase its readability.

Comment: I rewrote it as you said and it got rid of the error, thank you =). The reason why I was using `then` is because with my usual try-catch I keep getting the error `Promises must be handled appropriately or explicitly marked as ignored with the void operator`, and I still haven't figured out the way of getting rid of it without `then()` or using the `void` operator.

Comment: @HigoChumbo I haven't encountered that error myself. You should probably make another question here about how to fix it since it's not normal and there could be something wrong with your code/project. Also a little reminder, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you so it can also help other people in the future with the same issues as you.