# TypeScript: Error "Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected" inside a setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to write a generic retry function (function A), and use that on another function (function B) that checks some initialization status inside sessionStorage. The complete logic would be: it keeps checking whether the initialization status gets set to true, once it did, call function C. The retry will stop after 10 times with 1 sec delay in between.

Generic retry function (function A)

```
const retry = (fn: () => Promise<unknown>, times: number, delay: number): Promise<void> => {
  let error = null as Error
  const attempt = () : Promise<void> => {
    if (times === 0) {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    } else {
      return new Promise(() => {
        fn()
        .then(() : Promise<void> => { return Promise.resolve() })
        .catch((err : Error) => {
          times--
          error = err
          setTimeout(() => attempt(), delay)
        })
      })
    }
  }
  return attempt()
}
```

checks status inside sessionStorage (function B)

```
const isInitialized = (): Promise<void> => {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem(INITIALIZED_KEY) === 'true') {
    return Promise.resolve()
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("error"))
  }
}
```

I am getting error "Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected" inside setTimeout(). Based on this post [TypeScript: type for returning an async function call inside a setTimeout()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67047463/typescript-type-for-returning-an-async-function-call-inside-a-settimeout) I shouldn't add return in front of attempt() which I removed. But it is still not working.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => { attempt(); }, delay)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: The error becomes "Promises must be handled appropriately or explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator" after I make the change.